# Separating photos from other images algorithmically?

Tags: algorithm

Can an algorithm be derived to classify digital images according to how they were generated, i.e. the classes would be:

- Real-world photograph captured with an actual camera.
- A Computer-Generated realistic scene.
- A hand-drawn image or a painting.

Could perhaps a Machine Learning approach, geared towards analyzing statistics of the signal provide sufficient insight on the problem ?
In that case, is there any known implementation of such algorithm publicly available ?

Comment: Putting online and use the google image advanced search ? :-p ( beside kidding, they might have publish (white) papers on that ).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your problem or need and the steps, if any, you've taken to solve it.

Comment: As it stands, this question does not specify what types of images will need to be considered, so I am closing as unclear. The question may be reopened if it can be edited to clarify what types of non-photographic images will be presented, and to request an algorithm rather than an off site resource recommendation.

Comment: See also [What topics can I ask about here?](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I would expect the histogram of real-world image to be a lot more noisy and chaotic that CG generated or CG-painted ( If image textures are not used ).
Of course, it's a pretty coarse criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Difficulty depends on what you really want to classify, i.e. what exactly your data base of images is made ok.
For simple hand-drawn or computer art, I would think of just looking the color histogram (but for complex art with gradients; but still these gradients are likely to induce a very smooth colormap).

At the other extreme, distinguishing realistic computer graphics image from reality is probably impossible.